# I am able to filter list views using none-indexed column even if the result will be more than 5000 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, list-view-threshold, indexed-column

We have a term set named Customer and we have a managed metadata site column named "mmcustomer" which allow multiple selection linked to the customer term set:-

[image]

and inside our document library which contains around 8,000 documents in the root folder >> i defined the following filter inside the list view to filter based on the non-indexed column :-

[image]

now there is at-least 6,000 documents with "mmcusomters" = "CustomerC".. so i thought that the list view will raise a threshold error.. but till now i am able to view the list view without any issues.. so has the threshold inside SharePoint online improved ? to be more than 5000 ? or what is happening ? as the "mmcustomers" site column can not be indexed since it allow multiple selection..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding List View threshold is still applicable to Classic View of SharePoint.

But according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59) link, it will work till 20000 items in SharePoint Modern View for List.